# How to wrap ALL components of react in a HOC?

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS is a great library, However, it misses some features which I found in Vue and Angular. These features can be implemented of course in React, however, they require extra code to be written.

Every react component, or every JSX element I should say has the following properties shared, which are given by React to us to consume:

1. `ref`
2. `key`

I wanted to add extra props:

3. `renderIf`
4. `fallback`

These props help in a way I can't describe when it comes to conditional rendering and filtering the views based on the logged-in user permissions and roles (and other conditional rendering use cases, of course).

In react, if we wanted to apply these props to our components, we would use a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) as follows:

```js
//  Disclaimer: you don't have to understand any of the code written bellow, the general idea is that this is a HOC.

import React from 'react'
import getVal from './getVal'

export default function EnhancedComponent(OriginalComponent) {
  return ({ renderIf: renderIf_ = true, override: override_, fallback: fallback_ = undefined, ...props }) => {
    const renderIf = getVal(renderIf_)
    const override = getVal(override_)
    const fallback = getVal(fallback_)

    const consumersComponent = <OriginalComponent {...props} />
    let render = fallback
    if (renderIf) render = consumersComponent
    if (override_ !== undefined) render = override

    return render
  }
}
```

Where every time you want to apply these props to your components, you would have to wrap every new component you create with `EnhancedComponent` as follows:

```js
export default EnhancedComponent(function Sidenav(){
  return <div> side nav </div>
})
```

Now, you can use your `Sidenav` component within your `App` component as follows:

```js
import Sidenav from './Sidenav'

export default function App(){
  return (
  <div>
    <Sidenav renderIf={(5 + 5 === 10)}/>
    <div>etc</div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

This API is great, but it has a drawback, which is, every time you want to apply these cool props (`renderIf` and `fallback`) you'll have to repeat these steps:

1. import Enhanced component to your file.
2. wrap your export with Enhanced component.

What I am looking for, is a method, or a way to inherit, or to add some props to the original react component class, somehow?

In react class components, I can imagine doing this on the `React.Component` class which we used to extend from in the past

```js
class Car extends React.Component{
  constructor(){}
  render(){
    return <div>I miss you </div>
  }
}
```

But in react functional component, how can we do that?

I want to apply these props ***by default*** everytime I create a new component, without wrapping my components in a HOC everytime.

Does React have a way to do that? To change its defaults ?

Comment: You can't, with function components you use composition (https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). In your case, it will be a wrapper component which is a common pattern: `<RenderIf>{children}</RenderIf>`. Moreover you can just inject props by traversing the components tree (using Children API) (I don't recommend).